# Page-Based application modification

Tags: iphone, ios

I have created standard Page-Based application in Xcode 4.2.1.

I need to change `ModelController.m`

It has method -

```
- (DataViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index storyboard:(UIStoryboard *)storyboard;
```

for each page this method create new `DataViewController`

```
DataViewController *dataViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DataViewController"];
```

I want to use only one `DataViewController` instance for all page in this application. To change method `viewControllerAtIndex` like this:

```
if (dataViewController == NULL) {
    dataViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DataViewController"];
}

dataViewController.dataObject = [self.pageData objectAtIndex:index];
```

But this does not work correctly.

Thanks for advance.

Comment: "This does not work correctly" is not useful to anyone. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

I think people need more detail about 'how' it does not work. If it creates multiple instances of DataViewController, have you tried putting if block into @synchronized block? Kind of shooting in the dark, but that is what I would try at first..

Comment: I can't good describe "how". But what help me putting if block into @synchronized block? Thanks

Comment: It helps avoiding multiple threads accessing the if block at the same time. If that happens, it is possible that [storyboard instantiate...] will be called more than once. It is hard to picture the situation that multiple threads access this piece of the code, but I don't know your entire code, so I thought it might be worth a try.

Comment: May be you think that my bug? No. It's template of Apple that normally create for each page new instance. And in a head of ModelController.m in comment you can read "There is no need to actually create view controllers for each page in advance -- indeed doing so incurs unnecessary overhead".